# Abstract Syntax Tree for this case?

Tags: java, c++, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to create an abstract syntax Tree for the following 2 C/C++/Java code pieces:

```
1) return j++-200*20-++A*7

2) return j++-200*20-A++*7
```

Can someone please explain their difference when it comes to their AST?

Comment: Why can't you create the AST yourself and compare them?

Comment: @Ira Baxter the problem is that i get the same tree...

Comment: For the differences between `++A` and `A++`, have a look at the [Increment/Decrement Operators (++/--)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/176/operators#t=201611200425069375529) page in the SO Documentation.

Comment: Regarding Gullie's comment:  you get different tree nodes for ++A and A++.  One of them is the "pre-increment++" operator, and one of them is "post-increment++".  With the tree nodes labelled correctly, you should get different trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return j++ - 200*20 - ++A*7` and `return j++ - 200*20 - A++*7` will have identical ASTs down to the node involving `A`. The first will have a `pre-increment A` node, while the second will have a `post-increment A` node.

Comment: how then i can "see" on the tree that A++ has a lower priority than ++A?

Comment: What do you mean by priority? The precedence difference doesn't matter here, so the only difference is that postincrement and preincrement are different operators, with different semantics. Maybe it would make more sense if you used the `@+` symbol for one of them, to emphasize the fact that they are different operators. While parsing the difference can be detected based on position.

Comment: I mean, `return x++` will first return the result and then increase x by 1. On the other hand `return ++x` will first increase x by 1 and then return the result... How I can describe this in a AST?

Comment: You don't. That isn't the responsibility of the AST. You have the operator, and those behaviours are the definition of the operators. It's like asking how to describe multiplication in the AST.

Comment: Regarding Andar's remark:  The purpose of the AST is to reflect *the syntax*.  The semantics are implicit in the interpretation of the tree nodes.  So the tree doesn't "worry" about the differences; just that they are different.