# Abstract Syntax Tree of this expression?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to create an AST of the following expression:

```
return -7%++x+--y-++k%u--
```

but it's quite complex and I am stuck, can someone please help me start?

Comment: What you tried? First draw the AST in plain paper, write some code and then ask for help.

Comment: A good start would be to specify what language this is supposed to be an AST *for*. From the enthusiastic use of pluses and minuses in confusing configurations I'm guessing C or one of its derivatives  (and then you should omit `return` since it's not part of the expression), but it's still a good idea to tag that explicitly.

Comment: Your next clue is `-7 % (++x) + (--y) - (++k) % (u--)`. Mix in additional operator precedence, bake for 2 minutes in a parser pre-heated to 200 degrees and the AST should pop out with a golden brown crust.

Comment: Didn't you just ask a similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/40700677/120163   Why isn't the answer from that enough for you to figure this out?  What AST did you draw for this expression?